# How to identify duplicate values in two columns in Openoffice Calc

Tags: openoffice-calc

I have two columns that have numbers in them. The other has the numbers only once, when the other has duplicates. The numbers in these columns don't match. I need to find all the numbers in column B that have a match in column A.

This probably explains it better:
A   B 
1   2 
2   2 
4   5 
6   5 
7   6 
8   6

I want to get a result like:

A   B   C
1   2   1
2   2   1
4   5   0
6   5   0
7   6   1
8   6   1

or any other way for me to identify the cells in column B which don't have a match in column A

I've spent hours googling and trying different solutions but no go, so a nudge to the right direction would be appreciated

Thank you

-M

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In cell C1 place:

```
=COUNTIF(A$1:A$6;B1)
```

And copy down.

Comment: =COUNTIF(A$1:A$6;B1) did the trick. Openoffice seems to use ; as separator for function attributes. But thank you for your help! I was stuck in a wilderness of LOOKUPS.

Comment: The use of , or ; as a separator depends on your country settings.